# Connecting to Couchbase with Scala?

Tags: scala, couchbase

I have a scala project and I am trying to connect to a couchbase bucket with Reactive Couchbase.  The relevant code looks like this:

```
object CouchDriver {



val system = ActorSystem("ReactiveCouchbaseSystem")

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val driver = ReactiveCouchbase(ConfigFactory.parseString(
    s"""
       |  buckets = {
       |    test {
       |       name = "test"
       |       hosts = ["localhost"]
       |       bucket = "test"
       |      }
       |  }
    """.stripMargin))


  def init = {
   var testBucket = driver.bucket("test")
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "test" do not match.
```

I don't understand however, as I have not set a password for the bucket!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you didn't set a password, and the reactive library requires it?

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: Enterprise Edition 5.0.0 build 2873

Comment: With 5.x, passwords are no longer on buckets. Instead, you need to create a user with a set of role-based permissions. I am not familiar with Scala, but you need to authenticate with that user. I assume `ConfigFactory` has some option to do that. If not, you can create a user with the same name as the bucket, and that should be backwards compatible (but you still need to specify a password)

Comment: Thank you!  The way I resolved it was by adding this to the default bucket:authentication = {
    username = "Administrator"
    password = "password"
    }